# Лагокомпенсация для агарио-подобной игры

Tags: javascript, c++, алгоритм, разработка-игр, сеть

Помогите определиться с алгоритмом лагокомпенсации для браузерной агарио-подобной игры. Общение клиента и сервера посредством websockets. То есть следует учесть, что вместо пропадания UDP-пакетов, мы столкнемся в случае чего с запоздалым приходом протухших TCP-пакетов. Я ознакомился с огромным количеством статей на тему лагокомпенсации для шутеров. С теорией вроде как все понятно, но на практике для аркадного варианта возникают вопросы.

**Подготовка:** сервер моделирует игровой мир равными промежутками времени - 1 тик = 50 мс. Для увеличения точности само моделирование производится 5 раз для одного тика, то есть по 10 мс. Важный момент - если прошло чуть более одного тика, остаток времени переносится на следующий тик. На каждом тике формируется кадр изменений и отсылается всем клиентам. 
На клиенте все объекты условно разделены на 2 группы - тела игрока и все остальные. ***Сервер моделирует мир по своему времени, ничего не откатывая.*** Пока со стороны клиента нет никаких временных меток. Все действия игроков собираются в буфер и применяются одновременно в начале следующего тика, так какбы действие было инициировано именно для этого времени.

**Предполагаемый алгоритм (на стороне клиента):** Тела игрока моделируются на клиенте в текущем времени не дожидаясь подтверждения сервера. Все остальные тела моделируются с помощью интерполяции с задержкой в 50 мс. Имеем два кадра - прошлый и будущий. Позиция тела интерполируется от прошлого кадра к будущему. По своевременному приходу следующего кадра происходит смещение кадров. Если произошла задержка очередного кадра - используется еще на 100 мс запасного времени экстраполяция или до прихода этого кадра. По истечению запасного времени тело останавливается.

**Непонятно следующее:** как при таком подходе грамотно сочетать разделение игрока на две части? Ведь противник, которого атакует игрок, на экране игрока находится слегка в прошлом (50 мс для интерполяции + сам игрок на полпинга впереди сервера). Получается сервер обязан откатывать позиции хотябы игроков (а в общем случае всех движущихся объектов) для точного просчета взаимодействия? Или можно как-то упростить алгоритм и расчеты? Возможно для такого плана игры нужен и вовсе другой подход?

Comment: отказ от UDP - следствие требования работы в браузере?

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian, да, ведь это именно браузерная игра, хорошо хоть веб-сокеты есть. Кстати посмотреть что уже реализовано можно по ссылке в моем профиле.

Answer (score 1):

на стороне сервера можно предугадывать позиции игроков.
Например, если игрок бежит, то зная его скорость, предыдущие координаты, и время последней синхронизации, можно примерно определить его текущее положение через синусы и косинусы. В эту формулу, кстати, можно ещё пинг добавить.

А насчёт "запоздалых пакетов", если я не ошибаюсь, то они приходят строго последовательно, и вроде как, не будет такого, что 1 пакет обгонит другой.

А насчёт "кадров" не очень понял схему. В своё время мы делали онлайн игру по такой схеме:
Игрок, допустим, жмёт кнопку бега прямо, тем самым отправляет на сервер информацию о своём действии и координатах. Сервер получает пакет, и рассылает другим игрокам, которые в данный момент его видят, ну и у них он тоже начинает бежать. Если игрок останавливается, то соответственно отправляет пакет, что он остановился, и свои точные координаты, а сервер рассылает эту инфу другим игрокам. Чтобы у других клиентов игрок не "телепортировался" резко, мы делали, чтобы он плавно перемещался на эти координаты по формуле "чем дальше игрок, тем быстрее перемещается".